# Como faço pra conseguir sortear uma quantidade X de números sem se repetirem em JS?

Tags: javascript

```
let user = require(`readline-sync`)

let loteria = {
    totalNumeros: "",
    intervalo: "",
    numeros1: "",
    numeros: [],
    numeroexcluido: "",
    sortear: function () {
        this.totalNumeros = user.questionInt("Informe quantos numeros deseja sortear: ")
        this.intervalo = user.questionInt("Informe qual o numero maximo: ")

        for (let i = 0; i < this.totalNumeros; i++) {
            this.numeros[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalNumeros + 1)
                    
        }

        console.log(this.numeros);

    }

}
```

loteria.sortear()

Este é o código até o momento, queria apenas aperfeiçoar ele mas to quebrando a cabeça e não consigo.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Miguel!

- Você vai fazer um loop, com o total de números que você irá querer.
- Você irá criar um array para adicionar os números não repetidos aleatoriamente.
- Primeiro você gerará um número aleatório dentro do loop.
- Segundo você vai verificar se esse número existe no array, se não existir, você pode fazer um .push nesse array com o número aleatório.
  Se isso acontecer (não existir um número no array e você colocar lá dentro), você teria que ir diminuindo o total de números para ele sair do loop!

Segue o código abaixo:

```js
let total = 20;
const numbers = [];
const maxValue = 100;

while (total > 0) {
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);
  if (!numbers.includes(number)) {
    numbers.push(number)
    total -= 1
  }
}

console.log(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugeria a criação de um array com todos os possíveis números de serem sorteados. Depois, removia desse array a adicionaria num novo com os números sorteados. Ao utilizar o `length` to array para obter o index aleatório e sabendo que se remove o número sorteado, não há hipótese de alguma vez saírem números repetidos.

Seria algo como:

```js
const totalNumeros = +window.prompt('Informe quantos numeros deseja sortear:');
const intervalo = +window.prompt('Informe qual o numero maximo:');
const intervaloArray = [...Array(intervalo).keys()];
const numeros = [];

for (let i = 0; i < totalNumeros; i++) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * intervaloArray.length);
  numeros.push(+intervaloArray.splice(index, 1) + 1);
}

console.log(numeros);
```